# Custom class in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt and fairly new to C++ but I need help with this issue.
I have a custom class called HybridStack and I want it to extend a QStackedWidget and a QMainWindow.
I want it to extend a QStackedWidget so that I can use as many pages as I need and I want it to extend a QMainWindow so that I could be able to make each page have it's own MenuBar with different content of menu for different page.

> I want to add this custom class HybridStack to Qt Designer by
>   promoting it from a QStackedWidget.

Is this possible? If it is, can you brief me on how to do this? If it's not possible then what's an alternative? Most importantly, I need to use it in the Designer because I need to use qmake

Comment: Have you check the document about how to [promote](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) a custom widget?

Comment: Yes I have. I was able to do so on other project but am not sure on how to do it on this one

Answer (score 0):

You can't derive from both QStackedWidget and QMainWindow, because both of those are in turn derived from QWidget. If you did so, you'd end up with the [Dreaded Diamond](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond). You'll have to use composition instead.

Even then, I'm not sure if it would work correctly to put a QMainWindow within a QStackedWidget, since it is designed to be a top-level item (i.e. its shown directly as a window, not embedded within another QWidget). Another way of accomplishing what you want (menu bar changing when the you change tabs) would be the following:

1. Make your top-level item a QMainWindow
2. Make the central widget a custom widget derived from QStackedWidget
3. When the item showing in the stack widget changes, you can call QMainWindow::setMenuBar to change the menu bar. Each widget within the QStackWidget could have its own QMenuBar instance that it uses for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try that